# cual es la sintaxis correcta de un INSERT en visualbasic y sql server?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, insert

He estado tratando de hacer un insert pero mi codigo es un desastre y no puedo encontrar el error:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=conexion...")

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim query As String = "
INSERT INTO Articulo (artid, descri, fecha, valor, stock, bodega)
VALUES (@artid, @descri, @fecha, @valor, @stock, @bodega)
"
        Dim artid As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextCodigo.Text)
        Dim descri As String = TextDescripcion.Text
        Dim fecha As DateTime = DateTimePickerinsert.Value
        Dim valor As Decimal = Decimal.Parse(TextValor.Text)
        Dim stock As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextStock.Text)

        Using con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=conexion..."),
          command As New SqlCommand(query, con)
            command.Parameters.Add("@artid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = artid
            command.Parameters.Add("@descripcion", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TextDescripcion.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = fecha
            command.Parameters.Add("@value", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = valor
            command.Parameters.Add("@stock", SqlDbType.Int).Value = stock
            command.Parameters.Add("@warehouse", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ComboBodega.Text
            con.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
        MessageBox.Show("Insertado correctamente")
        LoadDataInGrid()
    End Sub
```

Si sirve de algo, los nombres de las columnas de mi bd son:

```
Tabla Articulo

Codigo
Descripcion
Fecha_Ingreso
Valor
Stock_Minimo
Codigo_Bodega
```

el error que tengo actualmente al insertar es: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@descri".'

Comment: Si los nombres de las columnas son ...Descripcion.... La sentencia de inserción debería de mencionar esos nombres, y no otros. En el caso, Dice `INSERT INTO Articulo (artid, descri, fecha, valor, stock, bodega)` Cuando debería de poner después del nombre de la tabla los nombres de las columnas. Además en el values, ocurre algo parecido. Te da error porque pone @descri cuando el parámetro lo defines como @descripcion.

Comment: @Javi fer2 Muchas gracias tu comentario me sirvió mucho mucho! ni los de stackoverflow en inglés supieron ayudarme con esto xd gracias amigo ahora entendí mis errores. Le pondría upvote o algo pero no puedo.

Answer (score 0):

Yo como lo hago es de la siguiente manera:

```
        Try
            Dim cSentencia = "INSERT INTO mi_tabla" +
            "(str_agencia,str_rfc,str_direccion)" +
            " VALUES " +
            "(@agencia,@rfc,@direccion)"
            Dim command = New SqlCommand(cSentencia, Cnn)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agencia", Me.TextBox_agencia.Text.Trim)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfc", Me.TextBox_rfc.Text.Trim)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@direccion", Me.TextBox_direccion.Text.Trim)
            Cnn.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Cnn.Close()
            Me.Button_grabar.Visible = False
            Me.mensaje.CssClass = "alert-success"
            Me.mensaje.Text = "El registro ha sido dado de alta"
        Catch ex As Exception
            Me.mensaje.CssClass = "alert-danger"
            Me.mensaje.Text = ex.Message
            Exit Sub
        End Try
```

visita: https://vbpuntonet.blogspot.com/